# SSO Service Down when pulling code via Haoide

Tags: single-sign-on

[image]
guys, any idea about this error? I cannot pull code from Salesforce now. Thanks!

Comment: Not yet sure what the issue is. Have you tried using "login_type": "REST" instead of username and password?

Comment: This is fascinating Marcos,@GlenDeMarcos I just did it with the login type and it works, but how to understand the login type in this scenario? Do you have any idea?

Comment: It might have been a temporary issue. Login type REST uses Oauth to grant login access to haoide. Just different types of ways of obtaining a session ID.